# Отправить одномерный массив без индексов с помощью guzzlehttp

Tags: php

Как можно отправить сформированный GET запрос с помощью библиотеки GuzzleHttp в котором один из параметров должен быть **одномерным** массивом (без индексов)

Т.е. параметры в GET запросе должны быть такими: `opt=1&param[]=val1&param[]=val2`

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client()->get('https://www.url.com/api', [
    'form_params' => [
        'opt' => 1,
        'param' => ['val1', 'val2'],
    ]
]);
```

GuzzleHttp использует функцию формирования GET строки `http_build_query()` которая вложенный массив индексирует принудительно. В результате получается такой запрос:
`opt=1&param[1]=val1&param[2]=val2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как Guzzle поддерживает передачу в параметр `query` простой строки, то единственный вариант - формировать запрос самому. Т.е. что-то типа

```
$client = (new \GuzzleHttp\Client())->get(
    'https://www.url.com/api',
    [
        'query' => 'opt=1&param[]=' . implode('&param[]=', ['val1', 'val2'])
    ]
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 0):

```
$client->get('http://example.com', ['query' => ['param1' => 'value1']]);
```

Comment: ну это же не то, что нужно вопрошающему